# Can I play multiplayer across different platforms?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

While I and a friend are playing respectively Mass effect on PC and on Xbox, I was wondering if there was any way to play the same co-op game, or if the 3 platforms get totally separated in the multy?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no cross-platform multiplayer in Mass Effect 3. All players have to be on the same platform.