# Convert save game to a different platform

Tags: mass-effect-3

Since it's [not possible to play multi with a player on another platform](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/57152/21806), is it possible to **convert a savegame** from one platform (PC, XBox, PS3) to another platform?

By doing so, this might allow to switch from one platform to another to enable playing with a friend (supposing you have two retail copy on the same platform).

Comment: the only real benefit of moving your save is to gain the readiness/war asset for your single player, not sure if its worth the effort since you can edit those anyway.  If you just want to play together and enjoy multiplayer, then just do it without moving save files over

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can PC saves be imported into console version of Mass Effect 3?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/54112/can-pc-saves-be-imported-into-console-version-of-mass-effect-3)

Answer (score 3):

It's possible only between PC and Xbox 360. PS3 is not supported. Here is how:

[Can I transfer saved game files from my PC to my Xbox360?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/53213/13314)

[Can PC saves be imported into console version of Mass Effect 3?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/54112/13314)