# Does Mass Effect 3 multiplayer care about platform?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I play multiplayer across different platforms?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/57152/can-i-play-multiplayer-across-different-platforms)

Do XBox players and PC players play together in ME3's multiplayer mode? Or are they relegated to distinct games per platform?

Couldn't seem to find anything in the first couple pages of google results when searching about this. It would seem really dumb if PC players only match with PC players and Xbox with Xbox.

Comment: Odd, the other question hadn't come up in the searches when I began typing my question. Oh well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only play with other players on your platform. They all use different backends (Origin for PC, XBox Live for 360...) and your Multiplayer characters are tied to your console's account (so if your name is Bob on PSN, other players on PSN will see you as Bob), making them unique on that network, rather than tying them only to Origin accounts.

You're still tied to Origin for all Galaxy at War stuff and EA also uses it for DRM for extensions and to prevent cheating.

Comment: Really? I play PC, but my friend just bought the Xbox version, and it still asks him to create an EA account to be able to play online. I was hoping that meant it was all matched-up in the back via EA's servers. :(

Comment: @eidylon some stuff is tied to your Origin account, but it's still not cross platform. It's for Galaxy At War stuff  and DRM

Comment: @Rarity: I'm pretty sure all of your Galaxy at War stuff is tied to a single account, meaning you can play multiplayer on PC and have it effect a 360 game.

Comment: @MBraedley It is

Comment: @Rarity: that single account is your Origin account.  Maybe you should update your answer.  It's correct, but not really clear.

Answer (score 1):

Mass Effect 3 isn't cross platform due to the different methods of updating the game and sending patches on each platform.  CS:Go recently ran into the same wall and Valve decided to cancel the cross-platform capability as well in favor of regularly updating and patching the PC version.  Its just impossible to maintain the same patches and updates to all the platforms at the same time due to how each system handles them.

Comment: Aww can you link to where they announced the cross-platform cancellation for CS:GO?

Comment: @Ampersand just google it, lots of places reported it